# flask_cache and memoize - make_cache_key error: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, flask, memoization, flask-cache

I'm kind of new to using flask, and I want to cache the result of  a function that reads pickled data. I use `memoize` function from `flask_cache` as follows:

in `model_chacher.py`:

```
from flask_cache import Cache
import pickle


model_cache = Cache(config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})


class ModelCacher():
    @model_cache.memoize(50)
    def get_model(self, customer_ID):

        with open('/path/to/data.pickle', 'rb') as tf:
            model_args = pickle.load(tf)
            trained_classifier = model_args[0]

        return trained_classifier
```

in `flask_compose.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from controllers.topic import controller as topic_controller
from models.modelcache.model_chacher import model_cache


app = Flask(__name__)
model_cache.init_app(app)
app.register_blueprint(topic_controller.topic_controller_blueprint)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=80, debug=True)
```

and I call `ModelCacher.get_model(customer_ID)` in `topic_controller`:

```
from models.modelcache.model_chacher import ModelCacher
...
trained_classifier = ModelCacher.get_model(cls_str)
...
```

and after running `flask_compose.py` and sending a request I get the following result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/app/controllers/topic/controller.py", line 20, in classify
    return ModelCacher.get_model(cls_str)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cache/__init__.py", line 528, in decorated_function
    cache_key = decorated_function.make_cache_key(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cache/__init__.py", line 393, in make_cache_key
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cache/__init__.py", line 434, in _memoize_kwargs_to_args
    elif abs(i-args_len) <= len(argspec.defaults):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

**and my question is:** how to properly set up my cache? any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: WHAT SOLVED MY PROBLEM:**

as @stamaimer pointed out, I create and instance of my `ModelCacher` and that solved the problem, also I used cached from `flask_cache.Cache` instead of `memoize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_model` method your defined is a instance method instead of a class method. You use `ModelCacher.get_model(cls_str)` when call the method. Try to call it with `ModelCacher().get_model(cls_str)`. Or you can just defined it as a global function.

Comment: thanks for the good point @stamaimer! I just create an instance of my `ModelCacher` and that solved the problem, also i used `cached` from `flask_cache.Cache` instead of `memoize`